# Could someone explain what the following command does?

Tags: redirect, stdout

Could someone explain me what the following command does?

```
find / > allfiles.txt 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

It lists all files and directories in the directory tree in a file called "allfiles.txt", and discards errors (the `2>/dev/null` bit).